# Using ServiceStack OrmLite to delete rows with condition in other table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have the following tables in the database:

```
Table C    Table B    Table A
-------    -------    -------
Id         Id         Id
BId        AId
```

The BId column is a foreign key to TableB. AId is a foreign key to TableA. I want to delete all rows from Table C that is connected to a row in TableA. The following SQL (used in SQL Management Studio) does the trick:

```
DELETE [ns].[TableC]
  FROM [ns].[TableC] c
  JOIN [ns].[TableB] b ON c.[BId] = b.[Id]
  WHERE b.[AId] = 530
GO
```

I tried using the following code:

```
var query = connection.From<TableC>()
            .Join<TableC, TableB>((c, b) => c.BId == b.Id)
            .Where<TableB>(b => b.AId == 530);    
connection.Delete<TableC>(query);
```

But this results in an exception and from calling GetLastSql() I get:

```
DELETE FROM "ns"."TableC" WHERE ("ns"."TableB"."AId" = @0)
```

How can I use ServiceStack OrmLite to accomplish this delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for DELETE TABLE JOINS were just recently added to OrmLite and is available from v4.5.1 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: One question though, are NuGets on MyGet release-versions or are they beta/RC-versions?

Comment: @MartinA They are just interim pre-release packages that we deploy to in between our official releases that get published on NuGet.